# why plotting a (112,112,2) in matplotlib using imshow() is not possible?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, dimensions

why is it that we can not plot a matrix that has the shape (112,112,2) but doing it for shapes such as (112,112,3)is ok ?

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (112, 112, 2) for image data
```

why doesn't this error come up when trying to plot a (112,112,3) matrix ?

010101010101010101010100101010101010101010011010101010010101010101010

***UPDATE***
I get this image from the web([address of the image](https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/12/Authorized-PNG-Images.png)

and use plt.imread() to turn the image into matrix. and then use plt.matshow() to plot it.
this is the result:
[image]

so far so good, after doing 3dmaxpooling on the image:

```
def maxpooling3d(image_path,stride):
"""
image_path = the URL or the directory path of the image
stride = the strides for 3d data i.e (2,2,2)
"""

#MATRIXIFY THE DATA AND GET THEIR DIMENSIONS 
image_matrix = plt.imread(image_path)
d1,d2,d3 = image_matrix.shape

#RESHAPE IT 
image_matrix_reshaped = image_matrix.reshape(1,d1,d2,d3,1)

#MAXPOOL THE RESHAPED IMAGE MATRIX
max_pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(strides=stride)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([max_pool])
result = model.predict(image_matrix_reshaped)
return np.squeeze(result)
```

and then get the result :

```
result_matrix = maxpooling3d(image_path,(2,2,2))
```

now that I want to plot the maxpooled matrix, I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-249-941479181323> in <module>
----> 1 plt.matshow(result_matrix)

e:\Users\Keram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in matshow(A, fignum, **kwargs)
   2299         fig = figure(fignum, figsize=figaspect(A))
   2300         ax = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.09, 0.775, 0.775])
-> 2301     im = ax.matshow(A, **kwargs)
   2302     sci(im)
   2303     return im

e:\Users\Keram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in matshow(self, Z, **kwargs)
   7751               'aspect': 'equal',          # (already the imshow default)
   7752               **kwargs}
-> 7753         im = self.imshow(Z, **kw)
   7754         self.title.set_y(1.05)
   7755         self.xaxis.tick_top()

e:\Users\Keram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1445     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1446         if data is None:
-> 1447             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1448 
   1449         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

e:\Users\Keram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, filternorm, filterrad, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5521                               resample=resample, **kwargs)
   5522 
-> 5523         im.set_data(X)
   5524         im.set_alpha(alpha)
   5525         if im.get_clip_path() is None:

e:\Users\Keram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in set_data(self, A)
    709         if not (self._A.ndim == 2
    710                 or self._A.ndim == 3 and self._A.shape[-1] in [3, 4]):
--> 711             raise TypeError("Invalid shape {} for image data"
    712                             .format(self._A.shape))
    713 

TypeError: Invalid shape (256, 256, 2) for image data
```

Comment: Did you look at the docs before asking this?  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

Comment: yes. I can not find the reason "why" it does not support shapes like that. it only says these are the supported shapes: The image data. Supported array shapes are:

(M, N): an image with scalar data. The values are mapped to colors using normalization and a colormap. See parameters norm, cmap, vmin, vmax.

(M, N, 3): an image with RGB values (0-1 float or 0-255 int).

(M, N, 4): an image with RGBA values (0-1 float or 0-255 int), i.e. including transparency

Comment: Yes that is it.  What would m,n,2 represent?

Comment: I pick an image from the web and use max pooling and let's say the image is (224,224,4), after max pooling it gets turned to something like (112,112,2) and the problem is that I can plot the (224,224,4) but not the (112,112,2).

Comment: Yes but what do you expect that to look like?  What do each of the two matrices represent?  Maybe a complete example would make this more clear?